# No race condition: Two blocks with different locks but same shared data

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition, synchronized

I have two threads *thread_1* and *thread_2* calling different methods on the same object *unsafeObj*.

- *thread_1* calls `unsafeObj.incrementVAR_v1()` 10 times
- *thread_2* calls `unsafeObj.incrementVAR_v2()` 10 times

These two instance methods both have a `synchronized`-block with different locks (LOCK_1 and LOCK_2) **accessing the same instance field VAR**.

```
public void icrementVAR_v1() {
  synchronized(LOCK_1) {
    ++VAR;
    print("Thread 1: "  + VAR)
  }
}

public void incrementVAR_v2() {
  synchronized(LOCK_2) {
    ++VAR;
    print("Thread 2: " + VAR);
  }
}
```

Given that these two `synchronized`-blocks use different locks I would have expected `VAR` being accessed concurrently and thus causing updates being lost (`VAR` less than 20). That's however not what I'm observing. Can someone please explain to me why that's not the case?

Example Output:

```
Thread 2: 2
Thread 1: 1
Thread 2: 3
Thread 1: 4
Thread 2: 5
Thread 1: 6
Thread 2: 7
Thread 1: 8
Thread 2: 9
Thread 1: 10
Thread 2: 11
Thread 1: 12
Thread 2: 13
Thread 1: 14
Thread 2: 15
Thread 1: 16
Thread 2: 17
Thread 1: 18
Thread 2: 19
Thread 1: 20
```

Comment: Also I would expect that `unsafeObj.incrementVAR_v1()` would finish before the new Thread starts, try introducing a large count **and** some sleep time

Comment: `VAR` is a private int field of `unsafeObj`, thus: `private int VAR = 0;`

Comment: to make the first thread finish before starting the second one you can use join method for the first thread to make sure it would be in the running stage. Additionally, please give your program output too.

Comment: Can you show the definition of LOCK_1 and LOCK_2?

Comment: @Brank Victoria The locks are ordinary objects: `private final Object LOCK_1 = new Object()` and `private final Object LOCK_2 = new Object()`.

Comment: Can you try to use LOCK_1 in both methods and see how it works? Probably we are missunderstanding the functionality for synchronization blocks and they are executing synchronously if you use different locks.

Comment: I mean, that lock2 cannot execute the method due to lock1 is already taken. Nevertheless if you are using the lock1 in both methods, you have the lock1 already taken and the second method can execute, giving you the race condition that you are expecting.

Comment: @Brank Victoria When I use the same lock in both blocks it does behave correctly: The methods are called synchronously as expected, meaning that `thread_1` accesses `unsafeObj` first and `thread_2` accesses `unsafeObj` last.

Comment: I get sometimes the right result with each method running 10000 times. So don't expect it to work every time. Or expect that it will produce the "wrong" result. Might both happen, but with such small numbers, it may not.

Comment: So you are getting 10 times thread1 and then 10 times thread2?

Comment: Increasing the count in both threads (to 100'000 iterations) as @Scary Wobat suggested does result in lost updates! **So I guess my expectation that this would cause a race condition was right?**

Comment: @Brank Victoria Yes thats right.

Comment: @NullReference Yes, also When you write to System.out – it acquires a lock on the OutputStream instance

Comment: I guess this is because `++VAR` compiles to just two lines of assembly, which are not so likely to be separated unless the processor is super busy?

Comment: @RickyMo = exactly, trivial code that is also being `synchronized` when printing

Comment: @All Thank you all for your participation and your quick and illuminating answers. I reckon that the lesson has to be: **1)** Race conditions are tricky to reproduce and **2)** If you try to reproduce them anyways use a big number of iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I expected the concurrent access (due to having two different locks ) on the field `VAR` **does result in a race condition**, but in order to observe it one requires a big number of iteration (in my case 100'000 iterations in each thread). The lessons learned:

- ☝ Race conditions are hard to reproduce
- Use big number of iterations when trying to reproduce them

Answer (score 0):

just for fun to do in 10 (of course, it not guaranteed)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1=new Thread(()->{
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                icrementVAR_v1();

            }
        }
        );
        Thread t2=new Thread(()->{
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                incrementVAR_v2();

            }
        }
        );
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
    static Object LOCK_1=new Object();
    static Object LOCK_2=new Object();
    static int VAR=0;
    public static void icrementVAR_v1() {
        synchronized(LOCK_1) {
            ++VAR;
            Thread.yield();
            System.out.println("Thread 1: "  + VAR);
        }
    }

    public static void incrementVAR_v2() {
        synchronized(LOCK_2) {
            ++VAR;
            Thread.yield();
            System.out.println("Thread 2: " + VAR);
        }
    }
    public static void print(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

example output:

```
Thread 1: 2
Thread 2: 2
Thread 1: 4
Thread 2: 5
Thread 1: 6
Thread 2: 7
Thread 1: 8
Thread 2: 9
Thread 1: 10
Thread 1: 11
Thread 2: 12
Thread 1: 13
Thread 2: 14
Thread 1: 15
Thread 2: 16
Thread 1: 17
Thread 2: 18
Thread 1: 19
Thread 2: 19
Thread 2: 20
```